# Check the validity of the following argument

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

[image: problem]

According to my studies, an argument is considered valid if and only if the conjunction of the premises implies the conclusion.

i.e $$p(p \to [q \to (r \to s)]) \to s$$ is a tautology.

One way to do this is to show that the above function can be reduced to 1 with standard simplifications

please see my working out in the attached picture. I managed to reduce this function to 1 and thus the argument should be valid, however the answers says that the argument is invalid.

If I am wrong, then why am I able to reduce this function to 1?

If I am correct, please let me know

my solution:
[image: solution]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the counter example $p=1$ and $q=r=s=0$

\begin{align}
f=&p(p\to(q'+r'+s))\to s\\
=&1(1\to(0'+0'+0))\to 0\\
=&1(1\to1)\to 0\\
=&1\to0=0
\end{align}

> If I am wrong, then why am I able to reduce this function to $1$ ?

The problem is your last step, $(p'+p)(p'+qrs')+s$ does not equivalent to $1$. Instead apply Negation law indeed $(p'+p)=1$, and by Identity law it's $(p'+qrs')+s$.
\begin{align}
f=&p(p\to(q'+r'+s))\to s\\
=&p'+(p'+q'+r'+s)'+s\\
=&p'+pqrs'+s\\
=&\underline{(p'+p)}(p'+qrs')+s\\
=&\underline{(1)}(p'+qrs')+s\neq1
\end{align}

Comment: I'm having a serious facepalm moment right now! So obvious now that you point it out. Thank you!